# resetting conda channel priorities

Tags: anaconda, conda, channel

I am having issues with conda. After running commands such as:

```
conda install -c /my_conda_channel numpy --offline --override-channels
```

the default conda channel has now become 'my_conda_channel' so that each subsequent package from this channel supercedes the default channel, which is not what I want. I did the former just for testing purposes.

How do I reset the channel behaviour?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Change the order from `~/.condarc` so that `defaults` the first channel as

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
```

and add this line to it

```
channel_priority: true
```

or run the following code in command-line

```
conda config --set channel_priority true
```

then again run

```
conda update --all
```

Good Luck

---

Edited for new versions of conda. According to [conda doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html)

> As of version 4.6.0, Conda has a strict channel priority feature. Strict channel priority can dramatically speed up conda operations and also reduce package incompatibility problems. We recommend it as a default. However, it may break old environment files, so we plan to delay making it conda's out-of-the-box default until the next major version bump, conda 5.0.
>
> ```
> channel_priority (ChannelPriority)
> Accepts values of 'strict', 'flexible', and 'disabled'.
> ```

It still accepts the old values `true` and `false`

1. `true` := `flexible`
2. `false` := `disabled`
3. `strict` := this is a new value

Comment: Starting with conda `4.6.0`, `channel_priority` accepts values of `strict`, `flexible`, and `disabled`. 
> In previous versions of conda, this parameter was configured as either `True` or `False`. `True` is now an alias to `flexible`.
See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html
or `conda config --describe channel_priority`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to move your channel to the bottom of the priority list.
Run the command....

```
conda config --append channels my_conda_channel
```

You should get a response like this...

```
Warning: 'my_conda_channel' already in 'channels' list, moving to the bottom
```

Verify...

```
conda config --get channels
```

Which should give you something like...

```
--add channels 'defaults'   # highest priority
--add channels 'my_conda_channel'   # lowest priority
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your home directory and open `.condarc` in an editor. Go to `channels` and edit the priority:

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - my_conda_channel
```

Now `defaults` will be preferred over `my_conda_channel`. You can also delete `my_conda_channel`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me as of **April 2021.**

There are several `.condarc` files that need to be edited, to ensure desired channel priority:

1. `~/.condac`. Here you'll find "global" channels that get prepended to all the other channels added manually (`default` channel e.g., or `conda-forge` got here somehow in my case, even though I did not add it manually). Changing/adding other channels via command line interface won't supercede the top priority of the channels listed here
2. `.condarc` files in the anaconda root dir. This is where channels added manually end up (I would also check `~/anaconda3/envs/{env_names}/` for environment specific `.condarc` files).

If you want full control over channel priority:

1. Clean channels sections in the `~/.condarc` file (the top one).
2. Edit `.condarc` files per the desired channel priority manually, one file per environment (including base)
3. Set channel priority to `true` or `strict`
4. Check results of your edits with `conda config --show channels`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the channel priority as follows:

1. conda config --get
   This will list all the channels from lowest to highest priority
2. add channels by using
   conda config --add channels ---(your channel)
   The last channel you add gets highest priority.. so maintain the order. you can add channels, even if you already have them so that the priority order gets changed

Answer (score 0):

In the conda-meta directory for the enviornment, I added a file called 'pinned':

pinned:

```
tensorflow               ==2.2.0
tensorflow-base          ==2.2.0
tensorflow-datasets      ==1.2.0
tensorflow-estimator     ==2.2.0
```

Then, conda update --all didn't update the packages:

```
$ conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): - NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.8.4
  latest version: 4.9.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/ai


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    awscli-1.18.169            |   py36h5fab9bb_0         1.8 MB  conda-forge
    boto3-1.16.9               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          70 KB  conda-forge
    botocore-1.19.9            |     pyhd3deb0d_0         4.1 MB  conda-forge
    giflib-5.2.1               |       h36c2ea0_2          77 KB  conda-forge
    hypothesis-5.41.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         222 KB  conda-forge
    jpeg-9d                    |       h36c2ea0_0         264 KB  conda-forge
    libpng-1.6.37              |       h21135ba_2         306 KB  conda-forge
    pandas-1.1.4               |   py36hd87012b_0        10.5 MB  conda-forge
    tornado-6.1                |   py36h1d69622_0         644 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        17.9 MB

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  keras-applications-1.0.8-py_1

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  awscli                            1.18.168-py36h5fab9bb_0 --> 1.18.169-py36h5fab9bb_0
  boto3                                 1.16.8-pyhd8ed1ab_0 --> 1.16.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  botocore                              1.19.8-pyhd3deb0d_0 --> 1.19.9-pyhd3deb0d_0
  hypothesis                            5.40.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 --> 5.41.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pandas                               1.1.3-py36h66e3816_2 --> 1.1.4-py36hd87012b_0
  tornado                              6.0.4-py36h8c4c3a4_2 --> 6.1-py36h1d69622_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  giflib                                   5.2.1-h516909a_2 --> 5.2.1-h36c2ea0_2
  jpeg                                        9d-h516909a_0 --> 9d-h36c2ea0_0
  libpng                                  1.6.37-hed695b0_2 --> 1.6.37-h21135ba_2


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
hypothesis-5.41.0    | 222 KB    | ######################################### | 100% 
tornado-6.1          | 644 KB    | ######################################### | 100% 
boto3-1.16.9         | 70 KB     | ######################################### | 100% 
libpng-1.6.37        | 306 KB    | ######################################### | 100% 
awscli-1.18.169      | 1.8 MB    | ######################################### | 100% 
jpeg-9d              | 264 KB    | ######################################### | 100% 
botocore-1.19.9      | 4.1 MB    | ######################################### | 100% 
pandas-1.1.4         | 10.5 MB   | ######################################### | 100% 
giflib-5.2.1         | 77 KB     | ######################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/ai:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.2.0           mkl_py36h5a57954_0  
tensorflow-base           2.2.0           mkl_py36hd506778_0  
tensorflow-datasets       1.2.0                    py36_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0              pyh95af2a2_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-metadata       0.14.0             pyhe6710b0_1
```