# update conda behind firewall

Tags: python, updates, conda

I am trying to update conda but I am behind a corporate firewall.

I followed [these instructions](http://seanlaw.github.io/2015/12/23/fetching-conda-packages-behind-a-firewall/)

and using:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```

I managed to establish a connection.
However, when trying to update packages through conda (instead of pip), conda always tries to update **everything** and I receive the following connection broken errors:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to proceed? is there a way to update conda one package at a time?

### EDIT

Some of the packages gets actually downloaded and if I try to run the same command again they won't be downloaded again. However for most of them the download is not completed (I have now tried several times and it seems that is always the same packages that are left to be downloaded).

[image: error2]

### EDIT 2

output of `conda config --show`

[image: condaconfig]

Comment: set proxy in path maybe

Comment: @prashantrana hi, some extra detail on how to do that? =)

Comment: in temrinal run `set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_ip:proxy_port`

Comment: Can you share the output of `conda config --show`?

Comment: @AndreaNagy added the requested output

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the remote host closed the connection:

> WSAECONNRESET 10054 
>   Connection reset by peer. An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I would suggest to change the order of your channels and try to download from defaults first. You can find example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671425/9020666

You can also update single package by conda with:

`conda update _PACKAGE_NAME_`

e.g:

`conda update python`

Comment: @as I said in the question, when I try to update or install any single package, anaconda asks me to install and update everything. and I end up in the previous situation. I also tried to download from the defaults channel first. That didn't work either

Comment: Have you tried update conda? `conda update conda` Also you could try to increase the read timeout from 1 minutes to 3, that might help: `conda config --set remote_read_timeout_secs 180`

Comment: Hi, yes I tried `conda update conda` and I end up in the same situation. increasing the read_timeout time didn't help unfortunately

Comment: :( And I suppose adding the proxy server did not help either? What OS do you use?