# Anaconda always want to replace my GPU Pytorch version to CPU Pytorch version when updating

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, conda

I have a newly installed Anaconda3 (version 2020.02) environment, and I have installed Pytorch GPU version by the command `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`. I have verified that my Pytorch indeed runs fine on GPU.

However, whenever I update Anaconda by `conda update --all`, the following messages always shows:

```
The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  pytorch            pytorch::pytorch-1.5.0-py3.7_cuda102_~ --> pkgs/main::pytorch-1.5.0-cpu_py37h9f948e0_0
```

In other words, it always want to replace my GPU version Pytorch to CPU version. I have tried that if continue the update, it will install the CPU version Pytorch and my previous Pytorch code on GPU could not run anymore. I have also tried the command `conda update --all --no-channel-priority` but the message still shows.

To my knowledge I have never modified Anaconda channels or add custom channels. How can I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 3):

It's happening because, by default, conda prefers packages from a higher priority channel over any version from a lower priority channel.  -- [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html)

You can solve this problem by setting the priority of `pytorch` channel higher than the default channel by changing the order in `.condarc` -- [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48547046/6210807)

```
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
  - conda-forge

channel_priority: true
```

or you can upgrade it by specifying as option:

```
conda update --all -c pytorch
```

Comment: This was not a solution in my case (using `mamba` btw):  `- pytorch   1.10.1  py3.9_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0  installed               + pytorch  1.10.1  py3.9_cpu_0   pytorch/linux-64   86 MB`

Comment: I believe as of today you may also need a line `- nvidia` because https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ uses both pytorch and nvidia channels now

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was coming from conda trying to update `cudatoolkit` from 11.3 to 11.5 (these numbers will vary depending on when you read this).

However, if you go here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/, you will see which CUDA version is compatible with the current PyTorch version (right now PyTorch version is `Stable (1.10.1)`). It appears, from that link, that this version of PyTorch requires `CUDA 11.3`.

This is confirmed by the proposed one-liner to install PyTorch that fixes cudatoolkit's version to 11.3:

```sh
# (this is not the solution - unless you're doing a fresh install)
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

#### Solution for `mamba update --all`: pin `cudatookit` version

Use conda's `pinned` file: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning

```sh
vi /YOUR_PATH_TO/miniconda3/envs/YOUR_ENV_NAME/conda-meta/pinned

# And add a line to limit coodatookit version to 11.3
#        (or higher, depending on when you read this - see above)
cudatoolkit<11.4
```

Now `mamba update --all` doesn't try to update cudatookit and consequently doesn't try to replace GPU PyTorch with CPU PyTorch, because the dependency to cudatookit 11.3 is satisfied.